# Schema Linking cannot be created with 404

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry

We are evaluating Kafka Confluent Platform 7.1.1 in Docker.
We are trying to create a schema link according to https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/schema-linking-cp.html

We have two schema registries in different environments with basic auth.

I am trying to create a cluster link in the source schema container by the command

```
schema-exporter --create --name exporter-link --subjects ":*:" --config-file /home/appuser/config.txt --schema.registry.url http://source-schema-url:port/ --basic.auth.credentials.source USER_INFO --basic.auth.user.info user:pass
```

and getting

```
io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.exceptions.RestClientException: HTTP 404 Not Found; error code: 404
        at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.sendHttpRequest(RestService.java:297)
        at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.httpRequest(RestService.java:367)
        at io.confluent.schema.exporter.client.rest.ExporterRestService.createExporter(ExporterRestService.java:186)
        at io.confluent.schema.exporter.client.rest.ExporterRestService.createExporter(ExporterRestService.java:148)
        at io.confluent.schema.exporter.client.ExporterCommand.maybeCreateExporter(ExporterCommand.java:239)
        at io.confluent.schema.exporter.client.ExporterCommand.executeCommand(ExporterCommand.java:192)
        at io.confluent.schema.exporter.client.ExporterCommand.main(ExporterCommand.java:112)
```

Our config.txt

```
schema.registry.url=http://target-schema-url:port/
basic.auth.credentials.source=USER_INFO
basic.auth.user.info=user:pass
```

What am I doing wrong?
Does anyone faced with the similar issue while exporting schemas?
I have tried to find source code of *io.confluent.schema.exporter.client.rest.ExporterRestService* but no luck.

Comment: _tried to find source code_ - It's not open-source. You need to look at the registry server logs to find what is "not found" and see what requests are being made.

Comment: If you execute the command "telnet target-schema-url port" do you get a response?

Comment: The target schema is reachable. I don't remember the details. But if I am not mistaken, the endpoint works only in the Confluent Cloud Schema Registry which the schema exporter is trying to use.